# Got error 500 when try to read other calendars in Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

```
GET /me/events
```

will returns my default calendar events only.

Right now I am trying to read other calendars.

First I did

```
GET /me/calendarGroups
```

It returns

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('576552d5-3bc0-42a6-a53d-bfceb405db23')/calendarGroups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEGAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAADtIAAA=",
            "name": "My Calendars",
            "classId": "0006f0b7-0000-0000-c000-000000000046",
            "changeKey": "JNChQOAsRUyoL3s3Zbm58QAAcAE="
        },
        {
            "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEGAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAADtKAAA=",
            "name": "Other Calendars",
            "classId": "0006f0b8-0000-0000-c000-000000000046",
            "changeKey": "qU3PyJwbLk2ME1AW/lSG+AAAAAA+NA=="
        },
        {
            "id": "AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEGAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AABE-YjrAAA=",
            "name": "People's Calendars",
            "classId": "0006f0b9-0000-0000-c000-000000000046",
            "changeKey": "qU3PyJwbLk2ME1AW/lSG+AAARRPfCw=="
        }
    ]
}
```

It shows I have 3 calendars which is correct.

Then based on [the List events doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_events), I think I should use

```
GET /me/calendars/{id}/events
```

So I tried

```
GET /me/calendars/AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEGAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAADtKAAA=/events
```

But it returns 500 error with

> ```
> {
>     "error": {
>         "code": "ErrorInternalServerError",
>         "message": "An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.",
>         "innerError": {
>             "request-id": "53480d49-a721-40f0-ae6c-a19b5aa2a907",
>             "date": "2018-02-05T02:00:29"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` returned by `/calendarGroups` is the group's id rather than a calendar's id. The prototype should look like this:

```
/me/calendargroups/{group-id}/calendars/{calendar-id}/events
```

If you call `/me/calendargroups/AAMkADBlZTUwNTkxLWVmODgtNDVhNC1iZjhlLTdjNjA1ODZlMDI5MgBGAAAAAACUbnk-iwQZRbXMgkfKtmYhBwCpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAAAEGAACpTc-InBsuTYwTUBb_VIb4AAAAADtKAAA=/calendars` you should get back a list of calendars within that group.